# Doxygen: Is it possible to group C++ function parameters, i.e. have the same documentation without duplicating it?

Tags: c++, parameters, doxygen

Is it possible to group function parameters in Doxygen documentation so that I don't have to duplicate the comment? For example I want something like:

```
/**
  <...>
  @param {{a, b}} <long documentation>
*/
```

Doxygen output:

```
<...>
Parameters:

  a,b - <long documentation>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can just pass a comma separated list of parameters with @param, like so:

```
/** Sets the object's position.
 *  @param x,y,z Coordinates of the position in 3D space.
 */
void setPosition(double x,double y,double z)
{
}
```

And it will appear in the output as you would expect.